# Windows Server 2008 R2 Virtual Network Setup

Tags: windows-server-2008, nic, guest

Some background:  I'm very much new to networking in general, and virtualization in particular.  I'm trying to set up a series of VMs as we are transitioning to a thin client setup.  I have been supplied a limited number of static ip addresses.  The server is located in an offsite building which houses the network we use to connect to the internet, share folders etc.  The setup I've been trying to go for is this:

- The host OS (Windows Server 2008 R2) is bound to one nic using one of the static ips (say, Nic1 and ip 10.255.6.61).
- I've set up another external virtual network attached to another physical nic , and a virtual private network attached to no nic.
- There is one VM running the same os (as the host).  This VM is connected to both the external virtual network (and uses another static ip say Nic2 and ip 10.255.6.62) and also to the virtual private network (I gave it a static random ip 192.168.88.1 subnet mask 255.255.255.0).  This virtual private network is connected to all the other VMs.
- I'd like to share the internet connection with all the other VMs on the private virtual network, and so I installed the RRAS role on the server connected to Nic2, and selected the option to share the internet over the vpn.

I've run through the RRAS wizard a few times, trying different configurations, but none of them seem to be letting the other vms connect to the 'net.  The vms seem to connect to the virtual private network fine, they are assigned an ip address and everything, but no internet, and no rest of the network either.

The other problem is in general I connect to the vms with RDP.  Will that be possible with a setup like this?  i.e. will the vms show up as computers on the network?  If not, what are my other options?

Thanks!

~josh

Answer (score 1):

I've never used RRAS, so my answer will be a bit generic, sorry.

I'm a bit unclear as to whether "no rest of the network either" meant `10.255.6.x` or `192.168.88.x`. Obviously if the machines in the `192.168.88.0/24` network can't communicate with each other, that's the first thing you'll want to tackle, since then they can't access the RRAS server itself.

Maybe you could describe what selections you made in the RRAS wizard, as well as produce the output of the following commands from one client and the RRAS server:

```
ping 192.168.88.1
ipconfig /all
route print
nslookup www.google.com
tracert -d 10.255.6.61
tracert -d www.google.com
arp -a
```